# SharePoint Calculated Yes/No Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, yes-no-field

I've tried to create a calculated column in a SharePoint list that looks for a word in the title of the list entry and then returns yes or no based on if that word is included in the title or not.

```
=IF((FIND("word",Title)),"Yes","No")
```

All of the items that have the word in the title return "yes" as expected, however the items that should return "no", actually return as "#VALUE!" and I am not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ISERROR` let's you display something else than the error message. "SEARCH" is better than "FIND" as "FIND" is case sensitive and doesn't allow wildcard characters.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Word",Title)),"Yes","No")
```

[SharePoint: ISERROR Function](https://manueltgomes.com/reference/sharepoint-list-function-reference/sharepoint-iserror-function/)

Comment: Thanks very much Christoffer, this has solved the issue!